# How to completely delete a DB on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I have a small Ruby on Rails app, and I made a mistake creating a model and so on.

How can I fully delete its database? Not reseting migrations or dropping its tables, but to delete all db related files? (`schema.rb`, etc)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Destroy/Remove database in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649686/destroy-remove-database-in-rails)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To drop database

```
rake db:drop
```

Then for creating database

```
rake db:create
```

For migrations

```
rake db:migrate
```

For seed

```
rake db:seed
```

Answer (score 1):

Deleting these files will not remove the database from your system. You should never delete your `schema.rb` because it holds the structure of your database. (And *not* the database records themselves.) If you simply created a new model, Rails does not automatically create a database table (that's what migrations do).

If you still want to drop your entire database (the structure *and* data), this is the command you need (found when calling `rake -T`)

```
rake db:drop  # Drops the database from DATABASE_URL or 
              # config/database.yml for the current RAILS_ENV 
              # (use db:drop:all to drop all databases)
```

By default, `RAILS_ENV` is not set. If you called `rake db:drop` during this state, all databases *associated with this app* will be dropped. In order to drop, say, only development:

```
export RAILS_ENV=development
rake db:drop
```

You can do the same with `test` and `production` environments.